# Storing data using Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

The problem is I don't know how to store my inputs from console.

Here is my code:

```
for (int j = 0; j < arr1.length; j++) {
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.print("Select product code:        ");
    arr1[j] = reader.next();

    if (arr1[j].contains("A001")){
        mouse = 100.00;
        System.out.print("Enter quantity:               ");
        qty = reader.nextInt();
        amount = qty * mouse;
        System.out.print("Amount:\t\t\t    " + amount);
    }
    if (arr1[j].contains("A002")) {
        monitor = 2500.00;
        System.out.print("Enter quantity:               ");
        qty = reader.nextInt();
        amount = qty * monitor;
        System.out.print("Amount:\t\t\t    " + amount);
    }
    if (arr1[j].contains("A003")) {
        keyboard = 200.00;
        System.out.print("Enter quantity:               ");
        qty = reader.nextInt();
        amount = qty * keyboard;
        System.out.print("Amount:\t\t\t    " + amount);
    }
    if (arr1[j].contains("A004")) {
        flashdisk = 300.00;
        System.out.print("Enter quantity:               ");
        qty = reader.nextInt();
        amount = qty * flashdisk;
        System.out.print("Amount:\t\t\t    " + amount);
    }
    if (arr1[j].contains("A005")) {
        harddisk = 1500.00;
        System.out.print("Enter quantity:               ");
        qty = reader.nextInt();
        amount = qty * harddisk;
        System.out.print("Amount:\t\t\t    " + amount);
    }
```

and here is the code that must be the line of code where it will show the result of stored data.

```
System.out.println("");
System.out.print("Add item (y/n) " );
yn = reader.next().charAt(0);
        
if (yn == 'y' || yn == 'Y') {           
    continue;
}       
else if (yn == 'n' || yn == 'N') {          
    System.out.println("Code\tDescription\tUnit Price\tQuantity\tAmount");
    System.out.print(arr1[j]);
    if (arr1[j].contains("A001")) {
        System.out.print("\tMouse");
        System.out.print("\t\t"+mouse);
        System.out.print("\t\t"+qty);
        System.out.print("\t\t"+amount);
                
        if (arr1[j].contains("A002")) {
            System.out.print("\t\nMonitor");
            System.out.print("\t\t"+mouse);
            System.out.print("\t\t"+qty);
            System.out.print("\t\t"+amount);
        }
    }
}
```

The sample input must be:

```
Select product code: A004
Enter quantity: 2
Amount: 800
add item(y/n)?: y

Select product code: A001
Enter quantity: 1
Amount: 100
add item(y/n)?: n
```

then it will be stored in an array which would be the result but instead of getting both of the input arrays, I only get the 2nd input array instead both of them.

```
Code    Description Unit Price  Quantity    Amount
A001    Mouse       100.0       1           100.0
```

Comment: in the result part, where is the if checking this A004 ?

Comment: Where does j comes from in the second block?

Comment: I tried doing the if for A004 and still gets the same results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you are reading the user input, next you are overriding the information, because you are storing in variables instead of array.

Create an object like:

```
class Product {
  private String code;
  private String name;
  private Long price;
  private Integer amount;

  public Long getPrice();
  public Integer getAmount();
  public void setPrice(Long price) { this.setPrice(price); }
  public void setAmount(Integer amount) { this.setAmount(amount); }
...
}
```

Then, create an `Product [] productArr = new Product[anyLength];`
Now when you check if the input is A005 for example, you would store the object with the following information:

```
if (arr[j].contains("A005")) { 
        Product newProduct = new Product();
        newProduct.setPrice(1500.00);
        newProduct.setCode("A005");
        qty = reader.nextInt();
        amount = qty * newProduct.getPrice();
        newInfo.setAmount(amount);
        productArr[j] = newProduct;
}
```

Then when you need to print them, you just access by the index `productArr[j].getAmount()` for example.

Try as a recommended, But in the future if you want a better approach, it would be better to use a Map<String, Product> to map the A001 to your product, A002 ..., A003, ... and then when you need to print them you just get by key.

Comment: I don't get your idea, can you please enlighten me more. Sorry, I really do need help for this one. :(((

Comment: First, wour solution will not work, look carefully about the variable. It's not always harddisk, right? Second, he didn't ask about using new mechanism like map

Comment: I suggest change class with output properties: 
Code   -  Description - Unit - Price -  Quantity  -  Amount

Comment: He can store the information he wants in Info Object. The map is just a suggestion, that means it's Optional.

Comment: @JiggyPalconit if this is not helping, I will delete my answer

Comment: I get the idea but I don't how to do it, I don't any have idea about getter and setter methods using Array.

Comment: The array won't have getter or setter, just the Info Object. When you access the object by the index j, like `inforArr[j]`, you will be able to access to getters and setters of this object.

Comment: I see, but may I ask is there still a way to do it without creating a new object? Like I'd just use for loop to store the data that was entered then, display the result after it was stored in a another for loop.

Comment: The only other option is create an array for each information. Like priceArray, amountArray, and then access them when you want the result

Comment: So, in each if-else statement I have to add another if to determine the input price and ammount?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224783/discussion-between-jiggy-palconit-and-guilherme-alencar).